# Eclipse: Open JSP file on CTRL+CLICK of jsp path 

Tags: eclipse

I used to open a jsp file included in another jsp file by just click the path by CTRL+CLICK in eclipse. But for sometime now this is not working. Don't understand why!!!.
eg. <jsp:include page="../someFile.jsp" /> if we just hover over this path and CTRL+CLICK it used to open the file in new tab in eclipse. Help Guys!!!

Im using Eclipse Indigo.

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit to grasping at straws here, but it sounds like the default editor (or the editor specified for this specific file) has changed.  From the Navigator or *Explorer menu select the JSP file and right-mouse-button "Open With..." to see the available editors for JSP.  The checked editor in the list is the one you're using now.  Try the other editors to see if they support the CTRL-CLICK action.